# How to disable xubuntu touchpad

Tags: touchpad

I have a Lenovo T410, and the touchpad acts 'quirky' occasionally (cursor jumps around screen).

Is a toggle function that allows me to disable the touchpad when I want (and use the eraser pad), and re enable it when I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for your touchpad id using "xinput" command.
Then disable touchpad by

```
xinput disable <id>
```

Comment: thanks, I would like to maybe create a keyboard shortcut so I can disable and enable as convenient.